# How to pscp command to copy files into destination directory in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, pscp

I am using pscp to copy files between two windows machines.

If I use, without specifying the destination directory its working as expected as shown below:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> .\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact_pyth* Adminis
trator@1.1.1.1:/
interact_python.py        | 0 kB |   0.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

But When I specify destination directory its throws error:

```
S C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> .\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact_pyth* Adminis
rator@1.1.1.1:/C:\Users/Administrator/Desktop/
scp: remote filespec /C:\Users/Administrator/Desktop/: not a directory

S C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

I have tried with different slashes, but its not working.

Any idea to fix this please?

Comment: Have you tried taking away the leading slash?  Like `Administrator@1.1.1.1:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop`

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have tried this now... But I am getting same 'not a directory' error.